# What do we mean by building the instances of abstract class?

Tags: java

`CloseableHttpClient` is an abstract class and it is mention in the document of `HttpClientBuilder` that it build instances of `CloseableHttpClient`. 
But we can't build the instances of abstract class ?

Class `HttpClientBuilder` --> Builder for `CloseableHttpClient` instances.
`CloseableHTTpClient` is an abstract class.

I would like to know the meaning of the below line

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()
```

The Build method is returning object of type CloseableHttpClient.

Comment: it just returns subclasses of `CloseableHttpClient` which *implement* the abstract methods

Comment: Yes, abstract classes can't be instantiated, but we can instantiate their non-abstract sub-classes.